# formatting the gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
   Font-Names = "Arial" >

<Columns>

   <asp:BoundField DataField = "itemId" ControlStyle-Width="100" HeaderText = "ID" />

   <asp:BoundField DataField = "itemDesc" ControlStyle-Width="100" HeaderText = "Image Desc" />

   <asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="itemImage" ControlStyle-Width="200"

    ControlStyle-Height = "200" HeaderText = "Preview Image"/>

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

I have this gridview to display some data from database, how do I do, if I want the data to display like a table such as 3 column in a row and after 3 it will go to next row like a 3x4 table, it will display a next page button to display more data. Example like the e-commerce website they display a few product in the row and continue to display some product in the next row, and a next page button is provided.

Comment: You need to use datalist here.

Comment: gridview is a standard control and i dont think you can customize as you mentioned, i think a custom HTML+CSS control could implement what you want.

Comment: Yeah, i should use a datalist here instead of a gridview. Thanks guys!